# Yii : CActiveRecord::getAttributes() cause error "Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object"

Tags: php, yii

After I use  `CActiveRecord->findAllByAttributes()` , most of the times I want get the result data (which is the sub-array 'attributes' of every row of the return) only.

I read the doc, I think getAttributes() should be what i need, but it show up with this errror msg :
 `Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object`

---

I ask this question because I think am miss-understand getAttributes(),
so please tell me :

1. what exactly do getAttributes() works like ?
2. why do the return value
   of findAllByAttributes() is non-object ?
3. any other formal way to get
   the "Attribute" sub-array inside the return value of
   findAllByAttributes() ?

---

Below is references

---

What I do :

```
$data = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(), 'id < 16');
echo '<pre>$data ';
print_r ($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

Will return a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => User Object
        (
            [_identity:User:private] => 
            [newPassword] => 
            [passConfrim] => 
            [userNameOrEmail] => 
            [rememberMe] => 
            [success] => 
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [userName] => youShallNotPass
                    [email] => papapass@hoo.com
                    [password] => 46f94c8de14fb36680850768ff1b7f2a
                    [type] => 2
                    [lang_id] => 1
                    [subscription] => 0
                    [status] => live
                    [createDate] => 2014-08-04 18:22:15
                    [updateDate] => 2014-09-04 14:44:55
                    [remark] => 
                )

            [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 5
            [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
            [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_validators:CModel:private] => 
            [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
        )

   ......
)
```

---

The data that I want :

```
Array 
    [0] => Array(
            [id] => 5
            [userName] => youShallNotPass
            [email] => papapass@hoo.com
            [password] => 46f94c8de14fb36680850768ff1b7f2a
            [type] => 2
            [lang_id] => 1
            [subscription] => 0
            [status] => live
            [createDate] => 2014-08-04 18:22:15
            [updateDate] => 2014-09-04 14:44:55
            [remark] => 
    )
    [1] => Array(

                ......
     )
)
```

---

What I am using to work around :

```
function myGetAttributes($result){
    $returnArr = array();
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $data = $row->attributes;
        array_push($returnArr, $data);
    }
    return $returnArr;
}
```

---

I ask this question because I think am miss-understand getAttributes(),
so please tell me :

1. what exactly do getAttributes() works like ?
2. why do the return value
   of findAllByAttributes() is non-object ?
3. any other formal way to get
   the "Attribute" sub-array inside the return value of
   findAllByAttributes() ?

Comment: 1. `getAttributes()` returns the defined public attributes and their values.
2. Every `findAll` method allways returns an array. In this case an array of User objects.
3. There is no function build in to access the attributes out of the array of models. The foreach is the best approach I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this could help you:

```
   $data = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(), 'id < 16');

   $encode=CJSON::encode($data);

   $decode=CJSON::decode($encode);

   print_r($decode);
```

Comment: btw, if you only want id & name, you can use CHtml::listData($models,'id', 'name');

Comment: see "The data that I want" part in my question.

Comment: You 're right , you can try using the functions of the class CJSON I hope your results

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$values = array();
 foreach($data as $v){
       $values[] = $v->attributes;
  }
print '<pre>';
print_r($values);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: I will see it is more simple to call the findAllByAttributes(). Will you think Make a wrapper of createCommand() is good idea ?

Comment: so, if you know how do findAllByAttributes() works, please tell me. I have seen your answer in someWhere of internet already.

Answer (score 0):

`find...` family (`find`, `findByPk`, etc.) return an object of CActiveRecord (AR) but `findAll...` family (`findAll`, `findAllByAttributes`, etc.) return an array of AR objects to use in `foreach` or other loops. e.g. :

```
foreach(User::model()->findAll('confirmed=1') as $user) {
    echo CVardumper::dump($user->attributes, 10, true);
}
```

And about your questions:

1- `$model->getAttributes()` (or simply `$model->attributes`) return an associative array (`fieldName=>value`).

2- If there is no record matching your criteria, the returned value of `find` methods (all of them) will be null.

3- No, it's always an object because of the utilities of the framework which rely on this type. You can write a method inside your AR or a class such as `protected/components/Tools.php` and put the following code inside:

```
class Tools
{
    public static function getAttributes($models)
    {
        if(!is_array($models) {
            return $model->attributes;
        }
        $result = array();
        foreach($models as $model) {
            $result[] = $model->attributes;
        }
    }
}
```

and then, use it like `Tools::getAttributes(User::model()->findAll('confirmed=1'))`.

Let me know if the answer solved your problem.